# extract digits with positive and negative sign

Tags: r, regex

I have trouble with extracting digits with `+/-` signs before to it.

my example strings is like this

```
x <- c("alexander c/d=(+5/-1)","maximus a/b=(-4/1)", "thor e/d=(+3/-2)")
```

I try to extract digits before and after the forward slash `/` with their signs.

So I tried

```
before_slash=sub(".*=\\((-?\\d+).*","\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
"alexander c/d=(+5/-1)" "-4"                    "thor e/d=(+3/-2)"
```

and

```
    after_slash=sub("^.*/(-?\\d+)","\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
> after_slash
[1] "-1)" "1)"  "-2)"
```

OTH, the expected output

before_slash

```
+5 -4 +3
```

after_slash

```
-1 1 -2
```

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Before slash](https://regex101.com/r/eRjcYn/1/):

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("[-+]?\\d+(?=/)", x, perl=TRUE))
str_extract(x, "[-+]?\\d+(?=/)")
```

**Details**

- `[-+]?` - an optional `-` or `+`
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?=/)` - there must be a slash to the right of the current location

[After slash](https://regex101.com/r/eRjcYn/2):

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("/\\K[-+]?\\d+", x, perl=TRUE))
str_extract(x, "(?<=/)[-+]?\\d+")
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/M2xZL3).

**Details**

- `/` - a slash
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `[-+]?` - an optional `-` or `+`
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits